# LibreOffice Base: Connection to data source could not be established

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office, libreoffice, radix

I am trying to open an MS Access database in Base using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187389/is-it-possible-to-open-an-access-2010-database-file-without-using-wine-or-virtua#519571) .  (I've tried both .mdb and .accdb)

I can follow the process described by Gord with no problems until the last step, where it asks me to save the database in LibreOffice format.  I choose a filename (say mylinuxdb.odb), click OK, and then Base opens with this error:

```
The connection to the data source "mylinuxdb" could not be established.
        org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Note that it is complaining about the new .odb database, not the MS Access database.  Nonetheless, no data is imported.

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised answer:

It appears that this issue is specific to distributions like Linux Mint that install LibreOffice Base by default. Presumably in order to enable embedded HSQLDB databases they also install a rather old version of HSQLDB which conflicts with UCanAccess. To fix that, remove LibreOffice's copy of HSQLDB. For Linux Mint that would be

```
sudo apt remove libhsqldb1.8.0-java
```

---

*(original answer)*

I was able to reproduce your issue with LibreOffice 6.4.6.2 on Xubuntu 20.04. It looks like the setup instructions on Ask Ubuntu may need to be tweaked.

In the meantime try opening your .odb file, clicking through any errors. When Base opens, choose

Edit > Database > Properties …

and notice that the "Database URL" text box has "jdbc:" in front of it.

[image: URL.png]

so if the textbox contains

```
jdbc:ucanaccess:///home/gord/Documents/Database1.accdb
```

then apparently Base will try to use

```
jdbc:jdbc:ucanaccess:///home/gord/Documents/Database1.accdb
```

and that won't work. We need to have just

```
ucanaccess:///home/gord/Documents/Database1.accdb
```

in the text box (as in the screenshot above).

Comment: Thanks.  I have the textbox beginning with ucanaccess as in your screenshot.  FWIW, I'm using Mint 20.1 with LibreOffice 6.4.6.2.

Comment: Yeah, I added a note to the instructions on Ask Ubuntu. Previous versions of Base embedded the `jdbc:` prefix *inside* the text box, and depending on the shell's colour scheme it could be a bit misleading. Putting the prefix outside the text box is much clearer (IMO).

Comment: I tried LibreOffice 7.1.1 and am getting the same error, albeit with a more detailed path: `org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory /home/buildslave/source/libo-core/connectivity/source/drivers/jdbc/Object.cxx:189`   I'm going to see if I can dig up an older version of LO and get it to work.

Comment: Which desktop are you using with Linux Mint?

Comment: Cinnamon 4.8.6.

Comment: Well, I tried with LO 6.0.7.3 (version chosen somewhat randomly) and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks!  LibreOffice Base is opening my database now, but with tables only.  Does UCanAccess not support MS queries and forms?

Comment: UCanAccess should be able to read saved SELECT queries as tables, but it can't do anything with MS Access forms, reports, or macros.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate.  Oh well, I am happy that I can at least access my tables in Linux.  Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT (as per chosen answer) *"specific to distributions like Linux Mint that install LibreOffice Base by default"*. Such statements should be avoided as they are clearly very difficult to prove except with rigorous analysis of all other situations, which is clear was not done and in practical terms cannot be done.

I just encountered this message with an LO Base form which uses a MariaDB installation on Windows 10, using a JDBC connection with the mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar connector .jar. The form was created only minutes previously.

Interestingly, I happened to have a Python application running at the same time but, and I stress, this Python application ***does not use any kind of connection to any mysql database whatsoever***. Nor, being CPython, does it use Java in any way whatsoever.

I find that when I close the Python application I am then able to open the LO Base form. Furthermore, ***after*** having **first** opened the LO Base form I am then able to run the Python application.

As to why this ludicrous error should arise in these circumstances in the first place, I do not yet know. Chalk it down to yet one more LO anomaly and oddity around which you have to navigate by hook or by crook.

Answer (score 0):

A `JRE` is needed for this to work. In my setting of **Ubuntu Mate 22.04** none was installed per default.

My solution was to install `openJDK` and set the correct path inside LibreOffice Base.

More information can be found here:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/the-connection-to-the-data-source-xyz-could-not-be-established/46296